# Quarkus JWT with secret Asymmetric Key ES512

Tags: jwt, quarkus, smallrye

We are trying to integrate into our Spring microservices architecture with JWT authentication ES512 asymmetric key.
The quarkus microservice is supposed to decrypt the token with the public key, unfortunately it looks like Quarkus by default supports RSA-256.

How can I place quarkus with ES512 asymmetric key?

Comment: here quarkus-jwt guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt

Answer (score 1):

I Did it with this configuration:

```
#Algorithm
smallrye.jwt.verify.algorithm=ES512
#Mapping to populate groups from auth JWT token info
smallrye.jwt.path.groups=auth
# Path separator
smallrye.jwt.groups-separator=,
```